# Magento - pagination generating wrong URL

Tags: magento, url, pagination

My pagination works fine except for the url.
the link for page 2 is: example.com/products#%21p=2
when is should be:example.com/products?p=2

when I type the latter in the address bar it works fine. Here is the code which is generating the link:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getPageUrl($_page) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
```

Looks like the standard Magento code so i'm not sure why it's not working correctly.
Thank you in advance.
Sam

Comment: check the core code. The question mark is not rendering properly

Comment: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar.html#getPagerUrl I would check to make sure nothing is overriding this method, I would also double check your environment settings in PHP/Apache,etc.

Comment: I had the same problem when i changed template. Just update Vinagento to the newest Version! It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your case is like mine, my TemplateMonster theme for Magento uses Vinagento's Vpager extension, and I've managed to fix this like this:

edit file: 
/www/app/code/local/Vinagento/Vpager/Block/Page/Html

replace line 4:

```
return str_replace('?', '#%21', parent::getPageUrl($page));
```

with:

```
return str_replace('?', '?', parent::getPageUrl($page));
```

The nice little animated gif won't show up anymore, but the users will be able to change pages!

best of luck, Eduardo

Comment: Also, there is an update of the extension in Magento Connect. Make sure to read instructions on how to remove previous extension before adding the new one. ;)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-layered-navigation-pagination-pro-9047.html