# Magento "Shop By" URLs use "#%21" instead of a "?"

Tags: magento, search

I'm working with a new Magento installation and using the shop-by links give me

```
example.com/catalogsearch/result/#%21color=1&q=shirt
```

instead of

```
example.com/catalogsearch/result/?color=1&q=shirt
```

I'm not sure where I should look to begin fixing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: The closest thing I've found is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949696/magento-pagination-generating-wrong-url) which has a similar problem, but I have not yet found anything out of the ordinary in the core code. I'm thinking to re-upload all of the core files, but am saving that as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

we had this same problem and found that a plugin was changing the url with str replace

changing the ? for #%21

the plugin changes the url so that it can be identified by the javascript file and updated via ajax.

the plugin in our case was vingento there seemed to be some confilcts with other plugins. After disabling this plugin and code our filter and paging links work again, although not via ajax.

Hope this helps you